# How can I get RWD to work for mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I am building a SPA.  I have

in index.html, and I've got a few media queries such as:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px){
  .sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

When I open the site in Firefox, I'm shown a selection of device sizes, and when I choose the smaller sizes, the RWD shows up.  The sidebar slides down, images are smaller, etc.   All great.  The problem is when I open the site on a mobile phone (android), it's as if I haven't done any of that.  Google doesn't recognize the RWD changes either.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the "screen and" bit, maybe ditch that?

Comment: @oxguy3 – The screen is fine, and prevents that media query from being applied to things like print.  Not necessary to remove at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @media screen bit does work - however the host I was using wasn't allowing it.  I've since moved my website, and it's mobile friendly.  Just thought I'd leave this here in case anyone else runs into this problem.  The hosting was previously done through my school, so I don't have a lot of info to share about it.

Moving to a proper host (godaddy, although I don't actually recommend it, since they don't have any server side scripting) fixed the problem without any other changes being made.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that resolution on phones is getting so ridiculous that old-style media queries are basically useless for determining device.  Of course, my 5-inch phone doesn't actually have 2560 pixels on its screen, but it uses a "device pixel ratio" to treat each logical pixel as 2, 3, 4 or even more pixels.

So, accordingly, we can target that metric to determine devices.  Try changing your media query to something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 640px){
  .sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To target mobiles and devices and basically everything properly use this media query:

```
@media handheld,screen and (min-width:600px){}
```

I would also personally use max-width over min-width it makes more sense on downsizing and code grouping but that's probably my personal preference.